# Can non-repudiation be ensured without public-key cryptography?

Tags: symmetric, non-repudiation

Message authentication is ensured by using HMAC, which can be thought of as a symmetric-key construction.

Source authentication in multicast communications can be guaranteed using TESLA, which is again based on symmetric-key principles (although it basically works because of asymmetries in time).

However, neither HMAC nor TESLA ensure non-repudiation.

Is this a structural limitation of symmetric-key cryptography? Or is there some construct that ensures non-repudiation without using public/private keys?

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a structural limitation of symmetric-key cryptography? Or is there some construct that ensures non-repudiation without using public/private keys?

Non-repudiation implies that nobody other than the private key holder<s>*</s> could have produced the signature, which rules out symmetric constructions such as HMAC.

With a symmetric MAC (from a construction like HMAC), anyone who has the ability to verify a MAC also has the ability to construct one, so such constructions cannot be used to provide non-repudiation.

So in that sense yes, it is a limitation of symmetric-key cryptography.

While [Hash-based signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamport_signature) do exist, those are still an asymmetric cryptosystem with public/private keys, despite the fact that they use traditional hash functions.

### Note

[It is arguable](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/6766/95298) whether or not [signatures provide non-repudiation](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/how-to-achieve-non-repudiation/6108#6108), which [is a legal concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation). It is arguable that cryptography itself is limited in the capacity to provide non-repudiation.

Comment: Signatures provide non-repudiation assuming 1) it is difficult to forge a signature without the algorithm used to create it (i.e. the person's brain), 2) it is easy to verify a signature visually without any secret information, and 3) it is modify a document once the signature has been added to it without being detected. It's a lot easier to trust the integer factorization problem than it is that no one is experienced at signature forgery.